# Is it a best practice always keep database connection in a single instance?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I want to ask whether is good practice to have single instance of database connection or declare new every times when we needed? I have this two designs shown in below:

**This is database class:**

```
<?php
class Database extends PDO {
    //Variable declaration
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $passwd = "";
    private $username = "root";
    private $dbname = "";

    //Connect to DB when the class construct
    public function __construct($host=NULL, $dbname=NULL, $username=NULL, $passwd=NULL) {
        if(isset($host) && !empty($host)) {
            $this->host = $host;
        }

        if(isset($dbname) && !empty($dbname)) {
            $this->dbname = $dbname;
        }

        if(isset($username) && !empty($username)) {
            $this->username = $username;
        }

        if(isset($passwd) && !empty($passwd)) {
            $this->passwd = $passwd;
        }

        parent::__construct("mysql:dbname=$this->dbname;host=$this->host", $this->username, $this->passwd, NULL);
        parent::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        parent::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    }

}
?>
```

**Method 1 : Dependency Injection**

```
<?php
class User {
    private $db;

    public function __construct(Database $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    //Some update and insert below here
}

class Employee {
    private $db;

    public function __construct(Database $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    //Some update and insert below here
}
?>
```

So, I will do this when I want to use the classes:

```
<?php 
    $db = new Database();

    $user = new User($db);
    $user->update($id,$data);

    $emp = new Employee($db);
    $emp->delete($id);
?>
```

or the other ways?

**Method 2:**

```
<?php
class User {
    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Database();
    }

    //Some update and insert below here
}

class Employee {
    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Database();
    }

    //Some update and insert below here
}
?>
```

and when I want to use it I will:

```
<?php  
    $user = new User();
    $user->update($id,$data);

    $emp = new Employee();
    $emp->delete($id);
?>
```

Which method is preferable or better? Offer an explanation if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the dependency injection method is better because it avoids creating multiple connections to the same database.

The problem you will face though is to inject the `$db` object in every constructors of your class. That's where *Dependency injection containers* can help you. Their role is to handle creating objects (and thus passing the dependencies in the constructors).

Have a look at this article: [Understanding dependency injection](http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html) which shows an example using dependency injection with a container.

Answer (score -2):

Personally I usually like to have something like this for my applications, named sql.php and required on the top of each page. I really like this approach because it makes it really easy to make changes to any of the credentials or adding a new variable with a different table name in it. Helps with version control also.

```
// Vars
$host = "localhost"; // Host name 
$username = "blah"; // Mysql username 
$password = "999999"; // Mysql password 
$db_name = "db"; // Database name 
$main_table = "table11"; // Main CONTENT Storage Table Name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name)or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```